# Laravel Accessor Mutator to get/set date, hours, minutes

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I have a datetime attribute in my class called start_dt. When it's saved, it needs to be saved as datetime and when it's retrieved I need the date, hour and minutes on their own so that I can populate some fields in form model bound blade template. The same form is used for both a create and update.

What is the correct way to retrieve this attribute in the format that I require as explained above i.e. I need to populate the start_dt field with only the date part of the start_dt attribute but if we are creating a new user then it should default to todays date. Similarly the start_hr and start_min dropdown need to be pre-selected with the hour and minute if it's and update and '00' if we are creating a new user.

In the database the start_dt attribute is stored as datetime value e.g 2015-11-11 12:38:00. So when we are saving I need to update the hrs and minutes that were selected from the dropdowns. How can you do this?

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $dates = ['start_dt'];

    public function setStartDtAttribute($startDt, $startHr, $startMin)
    {
        $this->attributes['start_dt'] = ;
    }
}


{!! Form::text('start_dt', isset($user->start_dt) ? $user->start_dt->format('d-m-Y') : Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

{!! Form::select('start_hr', [
   '00' => '00',
   '01' => '01',
   '02' => '02',
    ...
   '23' => '23'], isset($user->start_dt) ? $user->start_dt->hour : '00', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

{!! Form::select('start_min', [
   '00' => '00',
   '01' => '01',
   '02' => '02',
    ...
   '59' => '59'], isset($user->start_dt) ? $user->start_dt->hour : '00', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: Just read the Carbon docs its easy. Looks like you are overcomplicating things http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Comment: Not sure what's been over-complicated?

Comment: How can you pass the start_hr and start_min value to the setStartDtAttribute method. Looks like it would have to be done inside the controller method?

Comment: Its a bit hard to understand what you want to achieve but all these array assignments look like they could be avoided (I maybe totally wrong). And yes defo dont put the logic in the template you will get all sorts of headaches place for that is probably best in the model (or controller but fat models = skinny controllers is better)

Comment: See updated post for explanation of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So basically you want to take a date time and change the hour and minute values of the date?

Answer (score 0):

If you look under [date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) in the documentation, they have the example:

```
return $user->deleted_at->getTimestamp();
```

So in your mutator method, you could do:

```
public function getStartDtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::createFromTimestamp($value->getTimestamp());
}
```

Now you have a carbon object where you can access the year, month, etc. just by using things like `$user->startDt->year`. [Check here for the api](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters.)

For setting the current date for a new start date, you can create a new datetime:

```
...
$user = new User();
$user->startDt = Carbon::now();
...
```

Or to make easier, you could create a default value in your migration setup.

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    ....
    $table->dateTime('start_dt')->default(Carbon::now();
    ....
});
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do. I don't know how I can make it any clearer. When I save the date, I need to get the date part from the start_dt text field, the hour from the start_hr dropdown field and the minute from the start_min drop down field. How do I append all the fields to create a datetime value when I save using a mutator?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function setStartDtAttribute($startDt, $startHr, $startMin)
 {
   // i guess the $startDt is the column you want to update
    $splitDateTime = explode(" ",$startDt);
    $datePart = explode("-", $splitDateTime[0]);
    $timePart = explode(":", $splitDateTime[1]);

    // i dont understand the $startDT variable but the $startHr 
    // and $startMin i know its the hour and minutes part of the time
    // Now that the string is splitted into array lets replace the  
    // parts that you want to replace

    //index 0 of the $timePart is the hour and 1 is the minutes
    $timePart[0] = $startHr;
    $timePart[1] = $startMin;

    // Now lets join the arrays(ie. $datePart and $timePart) 
    // to form the datetime        

    $datePart = implode("-",$datePart);
    $timePart = implode(":",$timePart);
    $dateTime = $datePart . " " . $timePart

    $this->attributes['start_dt'] = $dateTime;
 }
```

You can choose to convert the final string to DateTime Object before you save. I hope this helps you.